# trac: modification roadmap thru style.css doesn't work

Tags: trac

I'd like to add new group on the trac roadmap progress bar. To do this I've modified trac.ini file with:

```
# Definition of an 'rejected' group:                                 
rejected = rejected
rejected.order = 2
rejected.css_class = my
rejected.label = rejected
```

where I've associated to css_class atribute value my.

Next I've created style.css file with one line only:

```
table.progress td.my { background: blue; }
```

The file style.css is read however the colour is not applied.
When I change back to the default one i.e.

```
rejected.css_class = new
```

the progress bar is updated and displaying yellow colour as expected.
However, it not displaying when I use

```
rejected.css_class = my
```

Any ides why?

Answer (score 0):

First, for reference, the authoritative documentation on the subject is [in trac.edgewall.org's](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRoadmapCustomGroups) wiki.

Now, did you try with other color expressions, like the common hex values, i.e. `#BAE0BA` (green Trac default for closed)? You could even try to set the full range of values for the `background` key like `none repeat scroll 0 0 #BAE0BA`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that CSS styles will override each other depending on the order in which they are encountered.  The page may be loading your custom style correctly, but if another stylesheet is loaded *after* your style.css and that stylesheet includes any styles that conflict with yours, then the later stylesheet will override yours.  Double-check that your custom stylesheet is being included and isn't being silently overridden by another stylesheet (I find the Firebug plugin for Firefox to be helpful in tracking down these sorts of issues).